# Efficient element-wise matrix operations in Julia

Tags: julia, matrix-multiplication

I need to perform a discretised convolution of (complex) matrices, and defined the following function in Julia:

```
function convolve(M::Array{Complex{Float64},2}, K::Array{Float64,2}, p::Int)
    (n,m) = size(M)
    res = zeros(Complex{Float64},n)
    for k=1:p
        for l=1:n
            res[l] += M[l,k]*K[l,end-p+k]
        end
    end
    return res
end
```

I use it like so:

```
M=complex(rand(2000,2000))
K=rand(2000,2000)
@time convolve(M,K,2000,0)
```

Now this is relatively fast and suprisingly, faster (about 3 times) than the vectorised version where I replace the inner loop with `res += M[:,k].*K[:,end-p+k]`. (I think it is due to a lot of memeory allocation for temporary arrays, I can live with that).

But a vectorised MATLAB code runs about 5 times faster:

```
function res = convolve(M, K, p)
    n = size(M,1);
    res = zeros(n,1);
    for k=1:p
        res = res + M(:,k).*K(:,end-p+k);
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get Julia to perform such element-wise multiplications as fast as MATLAB ? Is it an indexing problem ?

Note: I have checked with `@code_warntype` that there is no funny business with type indecision (no `Any` or `Union` etc), but the problem may be more subtle. The macro `@code_llvm` produces a suprisingly long output, but I am no expert so it is hard for me to see what is going on.

Comment: I think MATLAB automatically will multithread element-wise operations like that, while it's still experimental in Julia. Test it on a large matrix and see how many cores it uses.

Comment: Then try Julia with `Threads.@threads` in front of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I just checked that and Matlab does not seem to use more than 1 processor for a square matrix of 2000 by 2000 elements. Putting Threads.@threads slows down the julia code by a large factor...

Comment: Yes, threading in Julia is still experimental. There are still many bugs to iron out [like this one](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17395). You can use function-barriers and other things to kind of help, but there are just some problems for which is doesn't work too well right now. But you can see that once the threading story is worked out, this performance difference will be worked out as well.

Comment: It seems I get a x3 speedup by not using `end` but using a variable to store the size of matrix K... This gets me jsut 20% slower than matlab, so in practice almost the same...

Comment: Does attaching "--check-bounds=no" help (or @inbounds for the innermost loop)?

Comment: The bit of code used to test `convolve` and the resulting time would be helpful to bring the question into context.

Comment: Huh. I get the same x3 speedup too (Julia v0.4). That feels wrong. Using `end` shouldn't make your code 3 times slower. I would be tempted to file an issue although possibly wait a bit and see if anyone else shows up here who can explain what is going on...

Comment: @ColinTBowers In `@code_llvm` the `end` version has a call to `Base.trailingsize` which doesn't get inlined on my Julia 0.5 setup (Julia Version 0.5.1-pre+4)

Comment: for the vectorized variant of Julia with `res += M[:,k].*K[:,end-p+k]`, the commands `M[:,k]` and `K[:, end-p+k]` create temporary arrays at every iteration. but you can probably overcome that by using [`view`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/arrays/?highlight=view(#Base.view))

Comment: @DanGetz I just checked, and indeed the performance hit only occurs when you use `end` in a trailing dimension of an array with dimension greater than 1. So there is no slow-down in vectors, no slow-down in the first dimension of a matrix, but a huge performance hit in the second dimension of a matrix. I feel like this should be in the performance tips section of the docs. What do you think?

Comment: @ColinTBowers I'd classify it as a performance bug.  File an issue and I'm sure it'll get addressed.

Comment: @MattB. Done. [#19389](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/19389).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following version is faster on my machine:

```
function convolve2(M::Array{Complex{Float64},2}, K::Array{Float64,2}, p::Int)
    (n,m) = size(M)
    res = zeros(Complex{Float64},n)
    offset = size(K,2)-p
    (p>m || offset<0) && error("parameter p ($p) out of bounds")
    @inbounds for k=1:p
        @inbounds @simd for l=1:n
            res[l] += M[l,k]*K[l,offset+k]
        end
    end
    return res
end
```

Note the `@simd` addition which uses vector instructions currently in many CPUs.

EDIT: The performance hit in the OP's code seems to stem from using `end` in the index of `K` in the hot loop line. Redefining `Base.trailingsize` with `@inline` makes LLVM inline the `end` (on my machine) and make the two versions run about the same speed. The code used:

```
import Base: trailingsize
@inline function Base.trailingsize(A, n)
  s = 1
  for i=n:ndims(A)
    s *= size(A,i)
  end
  return s
end
```

See comments on the question for the issue [#19389](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/19389) regarding this.

Comment: @MattB. - true. Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks everyone ! This is a great answer. I almost got there in the meantime using `@inbounds` (with a prior safety check). I also wrote some (dirty) c++ and fortran90 equivalents to check for speed, and Julia is indeed the fastest now, together with Matlab. I can give that to someone if that is of interest.